# Show a hidden div on click a link after page reload in ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In my page I have many hidden divs. On page load the divs are hidden. while clicking a link the particular divs will display. I need it as after page reload the divs should display.

My code is here:

```
<li><a class="add_new" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showdivs()">Add </a></li>
<li><a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showdivs()">info</a></li>

<div id="add_new">hai.....</div>
<div id="info">heloo..</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#info").hide();
        $("#add_new").hide();
    });

    function showdivs() {
        var divs = $("#info,#add_new");

        //Show chosen div, and hide all others
        $("li a").click(function() {

            $(divs).hide();
            $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show();

        });
</script>
```

The code works but the page is not getting refreshed. I need the page to reload and then show the hidden div.

Comment: So you are trying to make divs appear when the link is clicked, but why should the page refresh?

Comment: I don't know if I understand, you want to sore the state of the visible divs? then you have to use cookies

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but I think you want to reload the page, because the divs are not show up, and the problem ist, that you add your clickhandler to show the divs "onClick":

```
function showdivs() { //this is called, when you click a link
        var divs = $("#info,#add_new");

        //Show chosen div, and hide all others
        $("li a").click(function() {// here the clickhandler is added, so the first time it won't work

            $(divs).hide();
            $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show();

        });
```

So you have to click twice to show the div. So here is my aproach:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#info").hide();
    $("#add_new").hide();
});

function showdivs( element ) {// element is this param
    $("#" + $( element ).attr("class")).show();
}

</script>
<!-- add parameter this-->
<li><a class="add_new" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showdivs(this)">Add </a></li>
<li><a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showdivs(this)">info</a></li>

<div id="add_new">hai.....</div>
<div id = "info">heloo..</div>
```

You can also do it like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#info").hide();
    $("#add_new").hide();

    $("li a").click( function () {
        $("#" + $( this ).attr("class")).show();
    });

});

</script>

<li><a class="add_new" href="javascript:void(0);">Add </a></li>
<li><a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);">info</a></li>

<div id="add_new">hai.....</div>
<div id = "info">heloo..</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you show a div, store the class in a cookie using `document.cookie = "divToShow=" + idOfTheDivToShow;`.

If you want to refresh the page, use `Location.reload()` in your javascript.

Then, use this function to get your `divToShow` cookie and show the related div:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return ""; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<body>
<li><a class="add_new" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showdivs()">Add </a></li>
<li><a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showdivs()">info</a></li>

<div id="add_new">hai.....</div>
<div id="info">heloo..</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery("#info").hide();
        jQuery("#add_new").hide();
    });

    function showdivs() {
        var divs = jQuery("#info,#add_new");

        //Show chosen div, and hide all others
        jQuery("li a").click(function() {

            jQuery(divs).hide();
            jQuery("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show();
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
```